# Trouble with jquery accordion width, scaling, and alignment

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, collapsable

i want the accordion to stretch to the width of the webpage and for the tabs to be able to stack on top of each other without space in between. I have to use images as the tabs.

This is how the homepage should look when the tabs/buttons are closed: i.imgur.com/aJMDepQ.png

When they're closed in the actual webpage, they don't stretch all the way to the edges and don't touch

This is what one of the accordion tabs actually looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ4zI.png

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Jennifer Wexler's Portfolio Site</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="container">
                <div id="logo">
                    <center><img src="images/logo.png"></center>
                </div>
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="nav", href="index_homepage.html">work</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav", href="http://www.google.com">resume</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav", href="http://www.google.com">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
                        <!--the code player practice. Issues with being the width of the site, but hover state is still working.-->
                        <div id="accordian">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                        <img class="fs_button", src="images/fashion_spread.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/fashion_spread_hover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/fashion_spread.jpg'">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><img class="fashionspread", src="images/fs_1.jpg"></li>
                                        <li><p>
                        A surreal fashion spread taking place in front of a theatre from the 1940s. It tells the story of a girl longing to be in the limelight. Original photography, styling, and experimental typography.</p></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                               </ul>
                           </div>
                </div>
        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
html {
    font-family:Didot;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
  background:#FDF9F0;
}

body {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
}

#logo {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
}

#nav {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:0px;
    width:50%;
    font-family:Didot;
    font-size:15px;
}

#nav ul { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top:145px;
    padding-bottom:145px;
}

#nav ul li {  
    display: inline; 
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
} 

.nav: hover {
    border-color:#000;
    border-width:thin;
}

.nav:link {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:6px;
    padding-right:6px;
} 

.nav:visited {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:6px;
    padding-right:6px;
} 
.nav:hover {
    color:#98b7a8;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-color:#000000;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    }  
.nav:active {color:#000000;}

#work {
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    width:100%;
}


.work {
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}


/*the code player practice*/

#accordian {
    width: 100%;
    padding: none;
    alignment-adjust:central;
}

/*list items*/
#accordian li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*links*/
#accordian ul ul li a {
    display: block;
    /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
#accordian ul ul {
    display: none;
    width: auto;
}
#accordian li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
```

jquery:

```
/*jQuery time*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fs_button").click(function(){
        //slide up all the link lists
        $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
        //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    })
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm having a hard time trying to follow what you're after. Are we able to see it somewhere?

Comment: thanks! I'm not sure how to put it somewhere. I've pretty new at all of this really. I'm not sure if you saw the screenshots I did but I was hoping that might give an idea of some of the issues.

Comment: The fact that no one else has commented or attempted to answer is an indication that your question is either unclear or overly complicated.

Comment: maybe unclear. i want the accordion to stretch to the width of the webpage and for the tabs to be able to stack on top of each other without space in between. I have to use images as the tabs. I might have to reconsider finding a different way to code this which brings me back to square 1.

Comment: This is how the homepage should look: http://i.imgur.com/aJMDepQ.png when the tabs/buttons are closed. When they're closed in the actual webpage, they don't stretch all the way to the edges and don't touch.

Comment: Put your information in your question, not down here in the weeds. :-)